# Accessing Annotation of an Entity of ontology using owlready

Tags: python-3.x, ontology, owlready

I want to access the annotation properties of an entity from an ontology using owlready library. In the screenshot below I want to access the definition of the selected Entity i.e. impulse control disorder.

```
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("./HumanDO.owl").load()
for subclass_of_mental_health in list(onto.search(label ="disease of mental health")[0].subclasses()):
    print(subclass_of_mental_health.id, subclass_of_mental_health.label) # This gives outputs (see below)
    print(subclass_of_mental_health.definition) # This results in error
```

Above is the code to access the impulse control disorder entity. I was able to access id by simply using dot notation (`<entity>.id`) but when i try to `<entity.definition>` getting

```
['DOID:10937'] ['impulse control disorder']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14348\3127299132.py in <module>
      1 for subclass_of_mental_health in list(onto.search(label ="disease of mental health")[0].subclasses()):
      2     print(subclass_of_mental_health.id, subclass_of_mental_health.label)
----> 3     print(subclass_of_mental_health.definition)

E:\Python\PythonInstall\envs\new\lib\site-packages\owlready2\entity.py in __getattr__(Class, attr)
    592     else:
    593       Prop = Class.namespace.world._props.get(attr)
--> 594       if not Prop: raise AttributeError("'%s' property is not defined." % attr)
    595       if issubclass_python(Prop, AnnotationProperty):
    596         attr = "__%s" % attr # Do NOT cache as such in __dict__, to avoid inheriting annotations

AttributeError: 'definition' property is not defined.
```

The ontology look like this [image: Disease Ontology] and you can download the actual file from here [Github link](https://github.com/DiseaseOntology/HumanDiseaseOntology/blob/main/src/ontology/HumanDO.owl)

My final goal is to read some annotations and store them but stuck at just reading them. To make it clear, I am not able to access any property other than id and label

Comment: I am also struggling with this. It seems that owlready2 only includes a set of annotation properties by default. From the docs: "The following annotations are available by default: comment, isDefinedBy, label, seeAlso, backwardCompatibleWith, deprecated, incompatibleWith, priorVersion, versionInfo" (https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/v0.37/annotations.html).

Comment: I have added my solution check it @fabad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after loading the data you need to add `sync_reasoner()` like the following:

```
human_onto = get_ontology("./HumanDO.owl").load()
sync_reasoner()
```

Then You can access all the property like the following:

```
human_results = human_onto.search(label =name , _case_sensitive = False)
for res in human_results:
    print("# ",res)
        
    for prop in res.get_properties(res):
        print("Property: ", prop)
        print("Value: ", prop[res])
```